# Output content based on the users input

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am new to PHP and would like to display some information based on the users input; creating an unordered list on the website with their details.

I have the following scripts in my WordPress theme...

**functions.php:**

```
/* Add/remove author profile fields */
function new_contact_methods( $contactmethods ) {
    unset($contactmethods['aim']);
    unset($contactmethods['jabber']);
    unset($contactmethods['yim']);
    $contactmethods['google_plus'] = 'Google+';
    $contactmethods['twitter'] = 'Twitter';
    $contactmethods['facebook'] = 'Facebook';
    $contactmethods['linkedin'] = 'Linkedin';   

    return $contactmethods;
}

add_filter('user_contactmethods','new_contact_methods', 10, 1);
```

**single.php:**

```
<ul style="margin: 0;">
    <li><a href="<?php the_author_meta('url'); ?>" target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/<?php the_author_meta('google_plus'); ?>" target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://twitter.com/<?php the_author_meta('twitter'); ?>" target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://facebook.com/<?php the_author_meta('facebook'); ?>" target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://au.linkedin.com/in/<?php the_author_meta('linkedin'); ?>" target="_blank"></a></li>
</ul>
```

---

How would I output the information from the users profile settings:

[image]

Only ***`if`*** they have placed content into any of the fields above.

For example, I don't wish to display an unordered list or list items which haven't been place into any of the fields:

- 
- https://plus.google.com/example
- 
- 
- http://au.linkedin.com/in/example

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `the_author_meta()` will `echo` out the value, so you can't really check it ahead of time unless you buffer the output or something. Instead you can use `get_the_author_meta`. The difference is that instead of `echo`ing the value, it just returns it. So you can look at the value, then use php's `empty` to see if it has been filled in, so your code might look like this

```
<ul style="margin: 0;">
<?php
$url=get_the_author_meta('url');
if (!empty($url))
{
?>
<li><a href="<?php the_author_meta('url'); ?>" target="_blank">
<?php the_author_meta('url'); ?></a>
</li>
<?php
}
//...
```

and a quick way to grab all the properties you want

```
<?php
$metaInfo=array('url','twitter','google_plus','facebook','linkedin');
$validProperties=0;
foreach($metaInfo as $infoItem)
{
$itemValue=get_the_author_meta($infoItem);
if (!empty($itemValue))
{
$validProperties++; //increments by 1
}
}
?>
<?php
if ($validProperties > 0)
{ //meaning we found at least 1
?>
<ul style="margin: 0;">
<?php
foreach($metaInfo as $infoItem)
{
$itemValue=get_the_author_meta($infoItem);
if (!empty($itemValue))
{
?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_author_meta($infoItem); ?>" target="_blank">
<?php the_author_meta($infoItem); ?></a>
</li>
<?php
}

}
?>
</ul>
<?php
}
else
{
//else we found none so display nothing! or do something like
echo "no data found!";
}
?>
```

Comment: **Fatal error:** Can't use function return value in write context in **../../single.php** on line **122**

Comment: hmm, I haven't encountered that before. Please try my edit then report back

Comment: Much better @chiliNUT.  Is there a way in which I can remove the `<ul>` and `</ul>` tags if no content has been placed in any of the fields for the users profile?

Comment: sure, you can loop through all of them once, sometimes called a first pass, and see if any are present. then, if you have determined at least 1 is present, do a second pass and display them in a `<ul>`, otherwise you can display nothing. see my edit ^^

Comment: **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected '<' in ../../single.php on line **131**

Comment: This line - `<ul style="margin: 0;">`

Comment: Ha wow that is sloppy on my part, I'm pretty terrible typing directly into this website instead of my IDE that highlights my missing brackets and semicolons. I'm glad you got it working! I've corrected my own code for completeness. And I didn't know about that `Can't use function return value` error! So I learned something too.